# Tensorflow GPU doesn't work in Pycharm

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm, tensorflow

When i'm running my tensorflow training module in pycharm IDE in Ubuntu 16.04, it doesn't show any training with GPU and it trains usually with CPU. But When i run the same python script using terminal it runs using GPU training. I want to know how to configure GPU training in Pycharm IDE.

Comment: What python interpreter is used in Pycharm? Is it the same as in your terminal?

Comment: @Maxim Yes.It runs on same virtual environment

Comment: Can you include the actual command from Pycharm? It should be the first line in a tool window. Example: here it run java -
 https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xqEQs0nuHnQ/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: same problem, Did you figured it out?

Comment: @khan Try changing python environment to global environment in pycharm interpreter settings. It worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was, the python environment for the pycharm project is not the same as which is in run configurations. This issue was fixed by changing the environment in run configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Below 4 steps should resolve your problem

1. Open terminal
2. activate your virtual environment
   conda activate your_virtual_env
3. launch Pycharm from terminal
   pycharm-community
4. You have to set environment variable for Python console [for the project].

[image]

5. Now run program from pycharm, it should run with GPU
   [image]